# Multi-touch for jQuery mobile colorpicker slider and canvas?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch, cordova, multi-touch

Right now I've got a working colorpicker slider, my local copy is slightly more developed because I've modified the jQuery mobile libraries, but I think [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8xpV/7/) should be enough to show my working concept.

I'm hoping that I might be able to work in multi-touch with the existing jQuery mobile framework I'm using, or with another library that won't conflict with jQuery mobile (like perhaps hammer.js?). I'm not really familiar with this at all, but I haven't seen any info on it in their docs, or if it's even possible with other frameworks.

I see in this library ([thumbs.js](http://mwbrooks.github.io/thumbs.js/)), it might be possible by adding something like:

```
element.setAttribute('ontouchstart', 'console.log("hi");');
```

Would it be possible to have the slider and canvas be active at the same time, so that a user could slide with one finger and draw on the canvas with another simultaneously?

I'd like an example of something similar but I haven't been successful in that either. I see lot's of info on js-related multi-touch and touch projects, [like this wiki](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Touch), but am not sure how to implement them into my project.

Answer (score 0):

hammer.js will work nicely alongside jQuery and jQuery mobile for multi-touch gestures. Also check out [this page](http://damien.antipa.at/2012/06/11/hammer-js-with-native-jquery-events/) where someone has adapted hammer.js to use the more convenient jQuery special event API.
If you're planning to support Android 2.x, see [this page](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill) for how to re-enable multi-touch in apps running on these devices.

However, what you're describing with using one finger to control the slider and another to independently draw on the canvas isn't as such a gesture and therefore I'm not sure you'll find an existing library that supports this. You'd need to independently track the x,y positions of both fingers simultaneously. Looking at the hammer.js source code, it does seem possible to extract the x,y coordinate of each touch:

```
var pos = [], src;
for(var t=0, len=event.touches.length; t<len; t++) {
  src = event.touches[t];
  pos.push({ x: src.pageX, y: src.pageY });
}
return pos;
```

So you might be able to extend hammer.js or write some custom JS to extract this information and therefore track the slider position and canvas position simultaneously.